# Call grails plugin closure from Groovy class

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

I am using the AWS plugin for grails. I am trying to use the sesMail closure from a Groovy class, not a service or controller e.g. in a method:

```
String msgId = sesMail {

            from props.from
            replyTo props.replyTo
            to prop.to
            html props.body
        }
```

I am getting an error saying sesMail is not a method of the Groovy class. My questions are:

1. How can I call a plugin closure that is ordinarily available in grails service and controllers from a regular Groovy class
2. Following that I'm curious how these closures are defined and made available in the service and controller. I can't find a definition of sesMail in the plugin.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Question. And I appreciate that you are curious to find the root cause of your problem. Here are your answers:-

- You can directly call the [SendSesMail](https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/aws/ses/SendSesMail.groovy#L116) bean to send mail instead of calling the `sesMail` closure. Your groovy class would look like:

  ```
  class MyGroovyClass{
     def sendSesMail

     def sendSomeMails(){
          String msgId = sendSesMail.send{
                from props.from
                replyTo props.replyTo
                to prop.to
                html props.body
          }
     }
  }
  ```

  As you can see SendSesMail is not a service class it is just a POGO, so it will **not** be autowired in this groovy class unless you define that in `resources.groovy`. So:

Something like:

```
//resources.groovy
beans = {
   sendSesMail(grails.plugin.aws.ses.SendSesMail)
}
```

Also keep a note by using the above method directly you would be bypassing `grails.plugin.aws.ses.enabled` configuration. So you have to handle it explicitly.

- You can very well find the definition of `sesMail` method which is metaClasses over target classes to take a Closure as an argument here in [MetaClassInjector](https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/aws/util/MetaClassInjector.groovy#L50). This class is basically used to inject/add `dynamicMethods` from the plugin definition. You can find it as

[AwsGrailsPlugin](https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws/blob/master/AwsGrailsPlugin.groovy#L37) (Line: 37) --> [AwsPluginSupport](https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/aws/meta/AwsPluginSupport.groovy#L86) (Line: 86) --> [MetaClassInjector](https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/aws/util/MetaClassInjector.groovy#L50) (Line: 50)

You can also see in [MetaClassInjector](https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/aws/util/MetaClassInjector.groovy#L50) (around line 45 and 46), the target classes are controller and service classes. Hence you find the closure `sesMail` available in those 2 artefacts.

I hope it is clear enough to address your curiousness. :)

Comment: great answer thanks. the only gotcha I came across was to make sure the sendSesMail bean was not a singleton. As a singleton by default it caused big issues with overlaps of the to, from and cc addresses when multiple threads were sending emails. Anyway simple fix by changing the scope to prototype.

Comment: @ConorPower Was it singleton by default? I do not think so. I thought it is a normal utility bean and not a service class.

Comment: The bean definiation in the plugin is not a singleton. However when I add the bean definition to resources.groovy, it was creating a singleton instance (different from the one defined in the plugin as I had to inject the necessary credentials) and that's where the issue arose. Perhaps I should have declared my groovy class as a bean and used ref("sendSesMail") in there to get the plugin bean?